# Django: Random query without duplicates

Tags: django, random, sql-order-by, exists

When i run this query:

```
img = sit_img.objects.filter(cardinality=0).order_by('?').distinct('idImage')[:5]
```

I recieve a transaction error. The problem comes only when i combine order_by() and distinct() in a query. If this is a bug, there's another aproach using Django ORM?

[I founded people having the same error](http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com.es/2011/10/django-model-distinct-and-orderby-not.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used

```
{% for i in img %}
```

instead of

```
{% while i=img.0 %}
```

in my template, and the results show no duplicates now.

Answer (score 0):

4 Documentation.

When you specify field names, you must provide an order_by() in the QuerySet, and the fields in order_by() must start with the fields in distinct(), in the same order.

Might be the case with you ?